# My SQL Database error

Tags: mysql, drupal

I was running a successful (drupal) site using Mysql (I'm on Mac OS X) until I suddenly started to get the following error: "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in db_table_exists()"

I don't know what this means or how to fix it, but when I visit phpmyadmin I get the following message: "#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61"

@Mitch: I installed it using the acquia drupal dev desktop stack, although I also have MAMP installed. I tried restarting the servers using these programs and this is the error I got (above). Can you perhaps provide more detailed instructions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means your database is off (or crashing). You need to restart it. This will vary depending on how you installed MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to comment out the bind address in my.conf.

edit: no, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '`/tmp/mysql.sock`'

means MySQL can't be connected through the socket file.

Check if `/tmp/mysql.sock` is present (including permissions), if not check your `my.cnf` where it is (or run `mysql_config --socket`).

So you can either make a symbolic link or alternatively specify `unix_socket` path in your `settings.php` file (`'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',`).